Django 5: Within the form, filter data with another field of the same form
I have a question that I can't solve.
Form:

I choose country
I choose region 1
I choose region 2

Based on the country I chose, how can I filter the data for region 1?
Code
fk_country = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        label="Pais",
        queryset= PteCountry.objects.all(),
        required=True,
        error_messages={"required": "Introduzca Pais"},
    )
    
    fk_region_1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        label="Region 1",
        queryset= PteRegion1.objects.filter(fk_country_id__in=PteCountry.objects.filter(id=**?????**).values_list('id')),
        required=True,
        error_messages={"required": "Introduzca Region 1"},
    )

filter a list of values, based on a field of the same form

You need to do this in ajax, where you can populate the form data on field selection and update the relevant values...axios is a solid package for this
